# Join in Linq in DevExpress xpo

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have added two datatable using persistent class in Devexpess

```
 XPQuery<me_employee> EmployeeQuery = new XPQuery<me_employee>(XpoDefault.Session);
 XPQuery<mr_role> EmployeeRoleQuery = new XPQuery<mr_role>(XpoDefault.Session);
 var employees = from emp in EmployeeQuery join empRole in EmployeeRoleQuery on emp.me_role_pkey equals empRole.mr_pkey 
 select new { emp.me_pkey, empRole.mr_role_name };
```

It throws an error saying.

```
"Specified Method is not supported"
```

how to user join in linq in Devexpress

Thanks

Comment: Could you use the markup to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the article which explains how to use join in XPQuery:

[How to create and use the JoinOperand using LINQ to XPO and Criteria Operators](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1883.aspx)